# How to run mocha tests with reporter?

Tags: javascript, npm, mocha.js

When I run `npm test` it outputs:

```
 mocha ./tests/ --recursive --reporter mocha-junit-reporter
```

And all tests run well. But when I try to invoke mocha `./tests/flickr/mytest --reporter junit-reporter` I got:

```
 Unknown "reporter": junit-reporter
```

How to pass it correctly?

Answer (score 4):

From `mocha-junit-reporter`'s [readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-junit-reporter):

```sh
# install the package
npm install mocha-junit-reporter --save-dev

# run the test with reporter
mocha test --reporter mocha-junit-reporter --reporter-options mochaFile=./path_to_your/file.xml
```

Comment: @callback what's wrong? what is the console output?

Answer (score 2):

I spotted two issues in your command:

```
mocha ./tests/flickr/mytest --reporter junit-reporter
```

First issue is `mocha` in above is a mocha command from global node module. However, when executing `npm test`, it actually targets local `mocha` command inside our `node_modules` folder.

Second issue is the name of reporter should be `mocha-junit-reporter` not `junit-reporter`

### Solution

Workaround is to target local `mocha`

```
./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./tests/flickr/mytest --reporter mocha-junit-reporter
```

This is preferrable solution.

Alternative solution is to install `mocha-junit-reporter` for global node modules as below:

```
npm install -g mocha-junit-reporter
mocha ./tests/flickr/mytest --reporter mocha-junit-reporter
```

This is not too preferrable because you can target different version of mocha and mocha-junit-reporter in global compare to the one in local node modules.

Cheers